# Getting unique constraint violation error on SaveChanges despite searching first

Tags: c#, database, oracle, entity-framework, .net-core

I have a C# .NET 6.0 service, in which an OracleDbContext is added with Servicelifetime of 'Scoped' (so as far as I understand, each function call essentially gets its own instance of the DbContext).  This service runs in the background with a file watcher such that when a file is dropped into a particular location it will kick off some processing.  First it queries the db table to see if a record for the file exists...if not, then it will try to insert a record into the table.

This is the check for existence that comes back null (filename must be unique):

```
_dbContext.[table].FirstOrDefault(ext => ext.FileName == fileName);
```

Then this is the insert function that will be called, which even itself checks for existence first:

```
var existingRecord = _dbContext.[table]
               .FirstOrDefault(s => s.FileName == obj.FileName);

if (existingRecord != null)
{
    return true;
}

_dbContext.[table].Add(obj);
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

But after a while of this service running, we end up seeing issues where it will get to SaveChanges() and then that comes back with ERROR "ORA-00001: unique constraint (EPADMIN.[filename constraint]) violated".  The records *are* successfully inserted into the table, however.  When that starts happening, we restart the service and it is generally fine again for a while.

The whole process, save for the beginning of the service itself (the function that gets kicked off when the service is started), is synchronous.  The Db Context does have an execution strategy configured, such that it's using the default transaction isolation level of Read Committed.  At one point I tried specifying Serializable for transactions (prior to setting up connection resiliency) but that caused its own problems.

What I can do is when that particular error is encountered basically just ignore it and move on (since the record is there).  But that seems like a hack way to do it - I worry about subsequent inserts always coming back with that error once things get out of whack.  How do I either prevent them from getting out of whack in the first place, or basically reset the whole context if that happens?

I'll be happy to provide any other details that would be helpful.

---

Answers to questions in the comments:

_dbContext is the only context working with this database.

This service is the only thing that does anything with this particular table (there's no other web service or anything that interacts with it).

My apologies for misspeaking on the table itself:  Filename has a unique constraint on it, which is what the error says is violated.  The primary key is actually an ID column that is generated by the DB as Identity.  I've modified the text above.

Comment: Is `_dbContext` the only context working with this database?

Comment: As Denis mentioned, is there any other piece of software working on the same set of data? Also, what kind of service are we talking about? A windows service, a web service, ...? For example, if a webservice is hosted in IIS, is a recycling interval configured? There might be an overlap of old and new process running and if the file watcher triggers while the old process is not yet stopped but the new process already started watching, you would get such an error. Many other scenarios are possible depending on circumstances.

Comment: Please post the actual full exception text, actual entity class and table schema. I suspect that `FileName` is *not* the primary key. `The records are successfully inserted into the table` that means the error isn't thrown here, or the records are inserted by another context. `SaveChanges` uses a database transaction internally to persist *all* pending changes

Comment: `this is the insert function that will be called` that's a very strong smell. DbContext is a Unit-of-Work, it doesn't need extra `Insert` methods. Did you use the "repository" antipattern, and tried to insert multiple items using multiple DbContext instances to silence concurrency exceptions perhaps? `SaveChanges` persists *all* pending changes. If you add 100 items, it will insert all 100 of them in a single transaction. In fact, it will even persist any DELETEs and UPDATEs, which means your INSERT could easily perform 43 UPDATEs as well

Comment: It's quite possible that bugs in the "repository" code or the code that calls it are adding the same object again and again. The solution is to remove the antipattern, not check for existing records. If you have 100 truly new objects, `context.AddRange(allOfThem); context.SaveChanges();` is enough to add them. If the ID is database generated, `DbContext.Update` will perform an UPSERT based on the ID's value. Default values result in an INSERT, non-defaults in an UPDATE

Comment: *The records are successfully inserted into the table, however* -- But that's impossible if SaveChanges throws an exception. If the expected records exist after the exception was thrown, that means that the records *were already* successfully inserted into the table and that the current run tried to do that again.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be a **case** related problem, because the keys and the indexes in MSSQL Server are by default case-insensitive, while obviously C# string comparison not. Your code can not find the filename. So, it could be enough to change the first line of your code to:

```
var existingRecord = _dbContext.[table]
           .FirstOrDefault(s => s.FileName.ToLower() == obj.FileName.ToLower());
```

Comment: This is suggesting that the file name of the file has different casing than the file name in the DB table.  But that can't be the case, since it's inserting the record using the file name of that same file.  Maybe this would be good to do anyway, but I don't think it will fix the problem.

Comment: I appreciate it though

Comment: This query won't have any effect except slowing things down. EF LINQ queries are translated to SQL, they aren't run on the client. If `FileName`'s collation is case-insensitive, the matching will be case-insensitive. The only thing `ToLower()` does is prevent the use of any indexes on `FileName`, thus resulting in a full table scan. And `S` locks taken on all rows until the search completes

Comment: No. The Filename string field comparison on SQL isn't case insensitive, but the indexes are. So the indexes will be always used when possible, and there's not any read lock, unless otherwise specified.

Answer (score -1):

A the issue you're experiencing with the "ORA-00001: unique constraint violated" error suggests that multiple threads or instances of your service are trying to insert records with the same primary key simultaneously

One of many approaches is to try to wrap your existence check, insert, and SaveChanges operations in a transaction. This ensures that the operations are atomic and prevents concurrent insertions with the same primary key.

```
using var transaction = _dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction();
    
    try
    {
        var existingRecord = _dbContext.[table].FirstOrDefault(s => s.FileName == obj.FileName);
        if (existingRecord == null)
        {
            _dbContext.[table].Add(obj);
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        else
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        transaction.Rollback();
        // Handle exceptions or log the error.
    }
```

Comment: This will have no effect because `SaveChanges` already uses a transaction internally. The code itself has *serious* problems though and looks suspiciously like copy-pasta or a ChatGPT answer. For example, `using` *ensures* the transaction will be rolled back unless committed.